# node emit to php finished but continue working

Tags: php, node.js

I have a job that is being run in nodejs. The job takes around 40-50seconds.

I have to run the job from php in the Laravel Framework.

```
$_commands = [
    'echo "end deploy"',
    'echo "Starting script_j release=dev"',
    'node script_j release=dev',
    'echo "Finished script_j release=dev"'
];
foreach( $_commands AS $command )
{
    $tmp = \exec($command);
}
exit();
```

I can improve the php script run time by changing the exec command to

```
\exec("$command > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &");
```

But is there a way of instructing the nodeJs script to send a signal to the php exec function that the nodejs script is finished but then carry on working.

ie in the same way you do in a node app with express... send the `res.json()`  but continue the function...

---

A package that offers threading: https://github.com/audreyt/node-webworker-threads

```
var worker = new Worker(function(){
    postMessage("I'm working before postMessage('ali').");
    this.onmessage = function(event) {
        postMessage('Hi ' + event.data);
        self.close();
    };
});
worker.onmessage = function(event) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("Worker said : " + event.data);
    }, 5000);
};
worker.postMessage('ali');
```

However, when you call this script from a terminal you do not gain control of the terminal again till the parent and child process has finished.

By adding a `process.exit();` at the end of the script kills the parent task and the terminal that called the script is reactive again to the user but this also kills the child process resulting in the `console.log` not printing anything.

Comment: res is just a response print out of some kind, you might be able to use http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php to actually pick up line by line output and detect that the node.js script has signalled end and break the PHP in turn but node.js stays on

Comment: Another method is to fire off another node.js thread and have the original call function terminate

Comment: Sammaye Is it true that this is only possible with something like, https://github.com/audreyt/node-webworker-threads ?

Comment: Probably doable quickly with the built in node.js threading but that repo looks quite impressive, I would definitely give it a try

Comment: Hmm.. no joy, the threads created appear to be child threads thus when the parent is killed so are the children. Which is logical and nice to know but doesn't help with my OP :/

Comment: You can probably do it the other way round: launch the commands with `proc_open()` and do stuff when they're all done.